# How to use the Jsoup to parse internal and external hyperlinks

Tags: java, hyperlink, jsoup

I'm practising with Web Scraping and I was wondering how I could scrape only internal and external hyperlinks. I'm able to retrieve all the links of a page following the Jsoup documentation but I still don't get how to do this.

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: simple string matching among the result list against the site's base url?

Comment: If you want ***internal*** and ***external*** links - would that list not include ***all*** the links?  If you have followed the **JSoup Documentation** to get all the links... It sounds like your done!

Comment: @Y2020-09 my goal was to retrieve them individually.

Comment: I still don't actually know what your talking about ***Crock***, although now that you have an answer you like...  Best luck with your software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try Document.getElementsByAttributeValueMatching() method to find element by attribute name and attribute value with proper regex.

For example, find all elements have attribute name is "href" and attribute value starting with https://example.com

```
    Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://example.com").get();
    Elements elements = document.getElementsByAttributeValueMatching("href", "^https://example.com");

    for (Element element : elements) {
        System.out.println(element.attr("href"));
    }
```

There are also some similar methods:

```
Document.getElementsByAttributeValueStarting()
Document.getElementsByAttributeValueContaining()
```